# Inner Join - Alocar vetor em R

Tags: r, inner-join

Estou tentando fazer um inner_join entre duas tabelas por uma coluna comum "codigo_estado". No entanto, está dando um erro de "alocar vetor de tamanho 1,4 gb".

Código:

```
arquivo_antigo_filtrado<- arquivo_antigo %>% select(codigo_estado,PV, PP, PSD, PSCF)
colnames(arquivo_antigo_filtrado) = c("codigo_estado","pv_antigo", "pp_antigo", "psd_antigo", "pscf_antigo")
arquivo_atual_validado<-inner_join(arquivo_atual,arquivo_antigo_filtrado,by="codigo_estado")
```

Dataset:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Seu computador não esta conseguindo separar todo esse espaço na memoria pra fazer essa operação que você deseja.

Comment: `codigo_estado` tam valores repetidos? Que o R espera que os valores sejam unicos, se não forem eles são repetidos em todas as combinações possíveis, que é o que pode tá causando a criação desse vetor enorme

Comment: E como os dois data frame tem os mesmos numeros de linhas talvez o que você esteja querendo seja dlpyr::bind_cols ou cbind

Comment: Não será sempre o mesmo numero de linhas, poderá variar, só o primeiro que tem que ser igual.

Comment: Se `arquivo_antigo` vem de um ficheiro e se já não precisa dele, rmova-o do globalenv, `rm(arquivo_antigo)` para libertar memória. Depois disso, não é má ideia correr `gc()`.

Comment: @JorgeMendes faz total sentido, não tinha percebido isso. Tem alguma ideia de como resolver?

Comment: @Theorp Olha, aí é analisar seu join e ver se você não precisa colocar outra variável como condições ou retirar as linhas de um dos data frames. Que como o join opera na lógica de sql ele espera que as chaves utilizadas para a condição sejam unicas, aí é olhar seus dados e ver como se adequar a isso.